# GSM packet sniffer (for Nokia s40 series) to extract telephony information

Tags: java-me, gsm, telephony, nokia-s40

I need to extract telephony information of Nokia s40 series set via J2ME midlet:

a) IMEI
b) IMSI
c) Memory Information(Free and Total)
d) Battery Status
e) Operator name
f) Roaming status
g) Country code
h) Area code
i) Signal strength

But unfortunately there is no API available for there. I have tried to search it but everywhere it says that there is no API available for that like [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?220434-Telephony-information-S40)

So, I thought a packet sniffer may help me to analyze the packet and inspect it for the required information. Other solutions are also welcome

Comment: Where exactly do you want to sniff and where do you want the sniffer to run? Please note that a), b), e) f) g) and h) are transported via GSM protocols and not via IP, c), d) and i) are probably not transported via communication protocols at all.

Comment: @Bernd I want to run it as a service in the background like once it's started out would trigger  every hour and retrieve information mostly about i) signal strength . please let me know if that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Although the information that you are after is not exposed as APIs on Series 40 most of it is exposed through [Nokia specific System properties.](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/#!developers-guides/application-framework/system-properties/nokia-specific-system-properties.html) You can build your own API using them.

Comment: none of these properties seem to be working for S40. Do you have any idea of GSM or communiacation packet sniffing. Probably that would be a generic idea.

Comment: You can not do a sniffer for GSM on your phone, remember this is not TCP/IP we are talking about. Which property did you try? What was the phone you have used?

Comment: I am trying this 

System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.networksignal") and some other telephony info like IMSI and IMEI

but it returns null on S40 platforms. Any idea how to retrieve these information on S40.